# WPF - Resizing Children to Fill a Parent

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In WPF, I simply want to have a 'container' which has 3 textblocks.  I would like these 3 textblocks to be sized so they each take up 1/3 of the parent's width.  I noticed that the stackpanel sizes the last child automatically, but is there a way to size each child automatically?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752271.aspx) or a [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612624.aspx)

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Text="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
  <TextBlock Text="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
  <TextBlock Text="3" Grid.Column="2"/>

</Grid>
```

The grid is very common and in every WPF-App used a lot. However also the UniformGrid is very handy but not so well known.

Comment: You are specifying Columns, but are using Rows

Comment: @Timur Nuriyasov: Changed it. Thanks!